# How to Generate Gmail draft using Google App Script from Spreadsheet contains Table in the Body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, automation, gmail

I want to Generate a Gmail draft using Google App Script from Spreadsheet contains Table in the Body.

Below is the Screenshot of what input values I have and what type of output I want.

I shall be thankful if you could share the complete GS code, as I m new at Google App Scripts.

In Addition, I also want a Signature in the email Body, "Thanks and Regards" is my part of the body.

Also please note that Column E is dynamic, means may b it has 1 row and may be more than 1.

currently I am using this code.

```js
function Email_Loop_BL() {


const signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var index = 2;
var index1 = 2;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var data = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 10).getValues();
Logger.log(data)
for (;index1 <= data; index1++){
  var message2 = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
}

var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var ccmail = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
var subject = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
var message = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();


//var location = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
//var guests = sheet.getRange(index, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
//var eventColour = sheet.getRange(index, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
//var sendInvites = true;

  
const html = "<div> </div><br>" + signature;
const options = {
  htmlBody: message + data + html,
  cc: ccmail
}  
GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, '', options);




}// End of Function
```

[image: Input]

this is my input

[image: this is my output I want.]

this is my output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sendemail() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  GmailApp.createDraft(vs[1][0].toString().split(/\n/).join(','),vs[1][2],'',{htmlBody:vs[1][3].toString().split(/\n/).join('<br>') + '<br>' + vs[1][4].toString().split(/\n/).join('<br>') + '<br>' + vs[1][5],cc:vs[1][1].toString().split(/\n/).join(',')});
}
```

My Data in Sheet1:

[image]

The Draft:

[image]

You can add more emails to recipients and cc by putting them on separate lines within the cell but terminating each line with a `ctrl enter`.  Same is true with the invoices.

Comment: THANKS, IN ADDITION, I FORGET TO MENTION THAT I ALSO WANT TO ADD SIGNATURE IN GMAIL DRAFT.

"Thanks and Regards" is the part of my signature.

Comment: Also please note that Column E is dynamic, means may be it has 1 row or more than 1.

Comment: I changed that on my example because the code is easier if you just put them all in the same cell separated by `ctrl enter` but if you wish to change it back your way that's okay with me feel free to make any code changes that you desire.  In my situation you can put as many in there as you wish.  Same is true for recipients and ccs

Comment: thanks but can you make changes in my code to inseart table, because I have to use this code on multiple sheets.